# Accessing SharePoint Group that is "only visible to Group Members" as Admin using PowerShell Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: web-services, rest, powershell, sharepoint, soap

I am attempting to access/grab SharePoint 2010 group data (roles and permissions) via the PowerShell Invoke-RestMethod request.  I am having a difficult time accessing groups who have their group settings set to:

> Who can view the membership of the group? Group Members

I'm an admin so I should be able to access this data regardless.

How do I access this data when the group settings are set to: Group Members?

Do I need to leverage my credentials?  I'm not entirely sure how to pass credentials to the site.  I am running PowerShell v4.0 on my local machine and not on the SP production server.  I figured because I'm access a web resource I should be able to pass credentials and gain elevated permissions.

Please see below code:

```
      clear

      $CRED = Get-Credential
      [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = { $true }

      $uri = "http://{site}/_vti_bin/UserGroup.asmx"

      $soap = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'
      $soap+= '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'
      $soap+= '<soap:Body>'
      $soap+= '<GetRoleCollectionFromGroup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/directory/">'
      $soap+= '<groupName>TestGroup</groupName>'
      $soap+= '</GetRoleCollectionFromGroup>'
      $soap+= '</soap:Body>'
      $soap+= '</soap:Envelope>'

      [xml]$WF = Invoke-RestMethod $uri -Credential $CRED -Method POST -ContentType "text/xml" -Body $soap                

      $WF.Envelope.Body.GetRoleCollectionFromGroupResponse.GetRoleCollectionFromGroupResult.GetRoleCollectionFromGroup.Roles.Role
```

After running this code I get this error:

```
\\ xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">Group cannot be found.</errorstring>
```

I was successfully able to get other resources via UserGroup.asmx such as GetGroupInfo and GetGroupCollectionFromSite.  I don't understand what I need to do to access this data.  I am passing my user credentials via $CRED

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the SP groups are actually AD Domain Groups.  I tested the above code with "private" and "public" SharePoint groups and I could return the requested data.  When I try to get the same data from an AD group the code fails.  Does sharepoint mask AD groups?  Are they not considered a group?

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Using a `[PSCredential]` object with the `-Credential` parameter is only going to work if the SharePoint site accepts an anonymous connection and then issues a 401 status code, which would `Invoke-RestMethod` would then respond to by sending the same request with the credentials (I know it supports basic auth, it might support other schemes). If the site uses form based authentication, then you can't use this method.

You can use `Invoke-WebRequest` to hit the login form, use its ability to parse HTML to find the form, then re-submit with the data filled in, and make use of `-SessionVariable` and `-WebSession`, then you can use the same session variable with the `Invoke-RestMethod` call.